# php shell_exce return null when executing command

Tags: php, mysql

```
  $shell_query = "mysql -u username -p password --execute=' INSERT INTO `mawinkcms`.`tbl_current_push` (`id`, `magazine_id`, `push_keya`) VALUES(NULL, '175', 'checker');'";

  $test = shell_exec($shell_query);
  var_dump($test);
```

But i got only NULL Value as output. If any one can tell me what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems to be wrong.Try this:

```
mysql -u [username] -p -e "Enter your query here"
```

For more info: [Reference](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/run-single-mysql-query-command-line/)

Answer (score 0):

no space allowed between `-p` and password. or use --password

```
-p$password
```

or

```
--password $password
```

and to capture error message, use `popen()`

```
$handle = popen('/path/to/executable 2>&1', 'r');
```

https://www.php.net/popen